# Error accessing dictionary elements created from CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a file.csv that contains 4 rows:

```
sigle, "name", "location" 
ABC, "ABC company", "Montreal" 
BDE, "BDE company", "Quebec" 
FGH, "FGH company", "NY"
```

I created a method to load the file in dictionary, and a method to search an element:

```
def loadFile(file_name):
        reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_name, 'r'))
        return reader

def find_elt(file_name, search_name):
    NOT_FOUND =-1
    dictOjects= loadFile(file_name)
    for elt in dictOjects:
        print("elt: ", elt)
        if elt['sigle'].find(search_name) != NOT_FOUND: 
           print('Element Found')
```

I could print the first elt: elt:  {'sigle, "name", "location"': 'ABC, "ABC company", "Montreal"'}
But I get an exception on elt['sigle']:  KeyError: 'sigle'

Could you please help me on this? I tried during 2 days, but I could fix this problem.

Comment: The file.csv contains 4 lines:

Comment: Is that what's really printed out? If so, there's something wrong as the quotes are messed up.

Comment: Which python version do you use?

Comment: I am using Visual studio code with python 3.9

Comment: When I ran your code it gives me the right answer. which is 
`elt:  {'sigle': 'ABC', 'name': 'ABC company', 'location': 'Montreal'}`
`Element Found`
`elt:  {'sigle': 'BDE', 'name': 'BDE company', 'location': 'Quebec'}`
`elt:  {'sigle': 'FGH', 'name': 'FGH company', 'location': 'NY'}`

Comment: Have you execute the code for example with find_elt(file_name,'ABC'), if you don't have any exception you will have as result at the end:  Element Found